# get_the_content within foreach not the loop

Tags: content, php

I want to retrieve the content of posts within a foreach loop.

```
        $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts();
        $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
        $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
        $content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content );

        foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
            echo '<img src="'. $url .'">'. '<a href="'. get_permalink($recent["ID"]) .'"><h1>'. $recent["post_title"] .'</h1><h2>'. get_the_date() .'</h2><p>'. $content .'</p></a>';
        }
```

but it gives me an empty `<p>`. Is it not possible to use `get_the_content();` like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_the_content();` must be used in the loop for it to work as specified in the Codex.
To get post content in your case you have to use  `$recent["post_content"]` instead.

Comment: cheers dude, its working fine!

Answer (score 0):

You could also do the following;

```
$recent->post_content;
```